# Modular web applications

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, maven

I'm working on a web application (Spring, Hibernate, Apache Tomcat) with more interfaces (HTML, mobile HTML, XML, REST). So I decided to split application to more web apps to avoid mixing files from the interfaces. I have extracted core classes of the application (business logic, Hibernate DAOs) to external jar and included it to web applications. Everything seemed to be perfect.

But now I have realized there are more instances of the core on the server, more EntityManagerFactories, Spring contexts,...). When I will try to communicate over Spring beans (e.g. add scheduler task in one interface, remove it in another) or use Hibernate second-level  cache, it should break down.

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more webapps, you will have more Spring appcontexts as well. That is a possible workaround that splix suggested, but perhaps it's too much for your scenario (I would only do that if the application was really big)

I don't really know what you mean by XML interface. XML-RPC? Webservice?
For the

- mobile UI I would use [Spring Mobile](http://www.springsource.org/spring-mobile) (many resources there),
- REST Spring MVC, see tutorial [here](http://www.oudmaijer.com/2010/01/16/spring-3-0-rest-services-with-spring-mvc/),
- for HTML [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html) again,
- if XML means XLM-RPC, see sample [here](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2010/02/apache-xml-rpc-service-with-spring-3.html).
- for webservices: [Spring Web Services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/).

Have all your logic in a service layer, doesn't really matter if it's in an external jar or not if you aren't going to re-use it in the future, and have one Spring appcontext with many views.

Comment: So you suggest to place all views and business logic into one huge war?

Comment: basically yes. if there's any chance you will be reusing the logic, of course you can extract that to an independent jar. how many views all together do you have (approx)? having one 'huge' war is much better imho than having 4 spring appcontexts and redundant resource-handling etc.

Comment: It's architecture design of our future applications. We have done several applications with XML view (for special HW clients) and now we need to create web variants of these applications. As a "good designer" I thought it would be the best to split project into modules. It looks nice, every module can be developped by another team (developer), we can deploy only these interfaces our customer needs,... But now I found these problems.

Comment: Modularization of course is a good idea, but it doesn't necessarily have to mean you are creating several binaries or if in terms of development, projects.

Comment: yep, you can still build the separate interfaces / components in modules and then combine them via a .war module that depends on the constituent pieces if you'd like.  I'm a fan of splitting out the multiple interfaces into separate wars as it makes it easier to 'spin up' just more web services or more web ui VMs,etc..  the issues you mentioned with 2nd level cache can probably be handled by using theclustering configuration of the cache (ehcache or oscache,terra cotta,etc).  For other 'work' to be performed you could actually have a .jar that pulls that data from a work queue. lots of options

Comment: Thank you guys, you are right. The best and simplest solution is to create only one war. Meanwhile I have tried Cargo's uberwar [link](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Merging+WAR+files) but it's full of bugs

Answer (score 0):

I know few projects with same requirements. We had used 2 standalone servers: **API server** and **Web server**. API server have access to all data, and can execute some set of queries against it. Result object are serialized to XML, JSON or Protobuf. It's very easy to make using Spring + custom View Resolver or Jersey (i have two project - one based on spring, second on Jersey, an I suggest you to use spring)

Web server calls this API (using protobuf, for example), and prepare html answer to user browser, based on results (and there also can be some ajax calls to this API server).

Mobile app can access this API server without any problem too.

Comment: It's possible but too complicated for my needs.